# I need excel to average three different companies' data

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

```
Company Days    avg a   avg b   avg c
a        3          
b        2          
c        4          
b        3          
a        5          
c        3          
a        2          
b        1          
c        4          
b        5
```

Here is a sample of what I'm trying to do. I need Excel to sort thru the input data and give me an average of Company A's days, B's days, and C's days. I need  to be able to do this without using VBA. How do I start this?

Comment: Do you really want to *sort* the data, or are you just using that as a figure of speech?   And, yeah, have you tried anything?

Comment: You can use the AverageIF formula. The instructions on how the formula works are in Excel help.

Comment: Filter was the wrong word to use. I tried =SUM(IF(A:A="A",B:B,0))/COUNTIF(A:A, "A") and got one answer. When I used the table filters to just bring up one company and used the =AVERAGE function, I got a different answer. I don't want to use a pivot table since this is to end up in a different spreadsheet to show a snapshot as to how each company is doing for the month, then the total year. The year is already set up based on the monthly data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Company is Column A, and Days in Column B, you can use the below in C,

```
=AVERAGEIF(A:A,"a",B:B)
```

Then repeat in `D`, and `E`, changing the `"a"` to be `"b"` and `"c"` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a standard task for a pivot table:

[image]